# How to set current value in collection in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Here is a piece of code in edit.html.erb which does not work. The purpose of the code is to fill a form for editing. Collection is used with option of yes and no. How can I set the collection to the current 'active' value with :selected option?

```
<%= simple_form_for @category do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :name, :disabled => true, :required => false %>  
  <%= f.input :description %> 
  <%= f.input :active, :collection => ['Yes', 'No'], :selected => f.active %> 
  <%= f.button :submit %>  
<% end %>
```

The error saying the active is not a method in f.input :active, :collection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the `active` attribute for categories is a boolean, try:

```
:selected => (@category.active? ? 'Yes' : 'No')
```

Comment: It did not work. The Active collection only show Yes, even the active is false. Thanks.

Comment: Is the `active` attribute a boolean? It would make more sense for it to be a boolean, but if it's a string then try `:selected => (@category.active == 'Yes' ? 'Yes' : 'No')`

Comment: It works. Here is the code:<%= f.input :active, :collection => [['Yes', 1], ['No', 0]], :selected => (@category.active? ? 1 : 0)

Comment: You can use a lambda as well: `selected: lambda { |category| category.id == params[:category_id] }`